# Android Studio Gradle and Plug-in Error

Tags: plugins, gradle, android-studio

Since the last update, 1.0, I got this problem with gradle:

Gradle project sync failed. Basic Functionality(e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly.

I also get this plug-in error:

Error:The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins.

How do I recitify this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In one of your build scripts, you have both of these lines:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Note that the Android plugin in the second line could be `'com.android.library'` or possibly `'android'` or `'android-library'`. In any event this means that you're trying to have both the Java Gradle plugin and the Android Gradle plugin in the same build script, and these two are not compatible with each other. If this module is an Android module, then you need to keep the Android plugin statement; if it's a Java module, keep the Java one.

If you're trying to use some build script plugin or feature in an Android module that requires the Java plugin, then it simply won't work and you'll have to find an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

It's not always that you have two plugins name written sometimes it could be a problem because of updating of SDK i:e updating from sdk 19 to sdk 23.....

you just have to do following in this case....[for gradle image solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxdq0.png)
Here 23 is given place of 19 just change it in build.gradle file in your Application->src->build.gradle and not in gradle section